# How can i get the value from the entry and inject into the init function parameter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password


entry_user = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
#entry_user.insert(0, "Username")
#entry_user.bind("<Button-1>", del_value_user)
entry_user.pack(expand = "yes")

entry_pass = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
#entry_pass.insert(0, "Password")
#entry_pass.bind("<Button-1>", del_value_pass)
entry_pass.pack(expand = "yes")

sasha = TwitterBot(entry_user.get(), entry_pass.get())
```

The entry never send the values I typed in into `sasha = TwitterBot(entry, entry2)`

Meaning I want that inside tkinter interface, I type in two entries that supposed to be username and password and when I execute the function those values get injected. I think the problem is that `self.username` and `self.password` are defined inside of the `__init__` and so if those entries stay empty at the launch so i cant get them to inject. cause I can print my `entry.get()` values. I just cant make them replace the two first parameters of my `__init__` function. Does anybody knows how to help?

Comment: Explanation: You are getting the values from the entrybox as soon as its created, which means its empty and you are creating the bot with empty pass and username, you will need an event like button or something that will trigger the even and instantiate the class with the right values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        print("Username =", username, "   Password =", password)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

def create_bot(event=None):
    sasha = TwitterBot(entry_user.get(), entry_pass.get())
    print("started bot")

root = tk.Tk()

entry_user = tk.Entry(root, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
#entry_user.insert(0, "Username")
#entry_user.bind("<Button-1>", del_value_user)
entry_user.pack(expand=True)
# Log in if the user presses the Enter key:
entry_user.bind("<Return>", create_bot)

entry_pass = tk.Entry(root, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
#entry_pass.insert(0, "Password")
#entry_pass.bind("<Button-1>", del_value_pass)
entry_pass.pack(expand=True)
# Log in if the user presses the Enter key:
entry_pass.bind("<Return>", create_bot)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Log in", command=create_bot)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Your code wasn't working because as soon as your code created the entries it tried to get the data out of them (which obviously is an empty string) and created the `TwitterBot` object. To make it work you have to give the user time to enter their details in the entries by adding a button/binding to the user pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

I created a button and placed it at the bottom of the window. When you click the button it calls `create_bot` which creates the `TwitterBot` object.

Comment: @CoolCloud thx for that I edited my answer - I am not the best explainer.

Comment: i tried what you did. i think its the right answer as well. The thing is now its tell me that create_bot is not defined. meaning tkinter wont start cause the sasha(TwiiterBot) line is inside a function that could be called only after tkinter is open. how can i solve this ?

Comment: i also have of other functions that can be triggered only with twitterbot object sasha. so if its not created at the launch all of theses functions cant be loaded and it prevents tkinter to open gui

Comment: @MikeFisher If you post more code, I should be able to help you more. The problem is that you aren't thinking of the program using event-driven programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button as button


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        print("Username =", username, "   Password =", password)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        
    

    def open_br(self):
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()
        
    def end_br(self):
        self.bot.quit()
    
    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("http://twitter.com/login/")
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
        password = bot.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)



    def like_tweet(self, hashtag):
            bot = self.bot
            bot.get('https://twitter.com/search?q='+hashtag+'&src=typed_query')
            time.sleep(3)
            for i in range(1,8):
                bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
                time.sleep(2)
                tweets = bot.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet')
                tweetLinks = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@dir='auto']")]
                filteredTweet = list(filter(lambda x: 'status' in x,tweetLinks))
                print(filteredTweet)

                for link in filteredTweet:
                    bot.get(link)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    if drop2_var.get() == "Retweet":
                        try:
                            bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='retweet']").click()
                            bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='retweetConfirm']").click()
                            time.sleep(3)
                        except Exception as ex:
                            time.sleep(10)
                    elif drop2_var.get() == "Likes":
                        bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='like']").click()
                        time.sleep(3)



# def create_bot(event=None):
#         sasha = TwitterBot(entry_user.get(), entry_pass.get())
#         print("started bot")

sasha = TwitterBot("", "")

root = tk.Tk()


HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 400



#FUNCTIONS CLEARING ENTRY


def del_value(event): # note that you must include the event as an arg, even if you don't use it.
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    return None
def del_value_user(event): # note that you must include the event as an arg, even if you don't use it.
    entry_user.delete(0, "end")
    return None
def del_value_pass(event): # note that you must include the event as an arg, even if you don't use it.
    entry_pass.delete(0, "end")
    return None


def ex():
    root.quit()

#PROGRAM SETTINGS


root.title("Social Bot")
root.minsize(400, 800)
#root.iconbitmap("/Users/sashakharoubi/Desktop/BOOTCAMP/Week 9/Day 2/image/logo.ico")
root.config(background="#66b3ff")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height= HEIGHT, width = WIDTH, bd=0, highlightthickness = 0)
canvas.pack()

# background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'blue.png')
# background_label = tk.Label(root, image =background_image)
# background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#MAINFRAME

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#222f3e")
frame.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)


#SUBPART FRAME

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#E9E9E9", bd=0, highlightthickness = 0, relief="sunken")


#DROPDOWN MENU OPTIONS

OPTIONS = [
    "Twitter",
    "Instagram(not working)"
]

OPTIONS2 = [
    "Likes",
    "Retweet"
]

entry_txt = tk.Label(lower_frame, text="Welcome to Social Bot\n\nChoose an action to execute", font=("Montserrat", 15), bg="#E9E9E9", fg="black")
entry_txt.pack(expand = "yes")


#DROPDOWN MENU

drop_var = StringVar(lower_frame)
drop_var.set(OPTIONS[0]) 
drop2_var = StringVar(lower_frame)
drop2_var.set(OPTIONS2[0]) 


drop = OptionMenu(lower_frame, drop_var, *OPTIONS)
drop.config(fg="black")
drop.pack()
drop2 = OptionMenu(lower_frame, drop2_var, *OPTIONS2)
drop2.config(fg="black")
drop2.pack()


#ENTRIES


entry = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
entry.insert(0, "-->Topic to like or retweet")
entry.bind("<Button-1>", del_value)
entry.pack(expand = "yes")

entry_user = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
entry_user.insert(0, "----Type Your Username---")
entry_user.bind("<Button-1>", del_value_user)
entry_user.pack(expand = "yes")
#entry_user.bind("<Return>", create_bot)

entry_pass = tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg="white", fg='black', bd=0)
entry_pass.insert(0, "----Type Your Password---")
entry_pass.bind("<Button-1>", del_value_pass)
entry_pass.pack(expand = "yes")
#entry_pass.bind("<Return>", create_bot)




#BUTTONS

button_confirm = button(lower_frame, text="Confirm", bg="white", fg="black")
button_confirm.pack(pady=25, side = 'top')

button_open = button(lower_frame, text="Open Browser", bg="white", fg="black", command= sasha.open_br)
button_open.pack(pady=25, side = 'top')

button_log = button(lower_frame, text="LOG IN", bg='#54a0ff', fg="white", command =sasha.login, bd=0, highlightthickness = 0)
button_log.pack(pady=25, side = 'left')

button_launch = button(lower_frame, text="START", bg='#1dd1a1', fg="white", relief="flat", command = lambda: sasha.like_tweet(entry.get()), bd=0, highlightthickness = 0)
button_launch.pack(pady=25, side = 'right')

button_stop = button(lower_frame, text="STOP", bg="#ff6b6b", fg="white", command= sasha.end_br)
button_stop.pack(pady=25, side = 'bottom')

button_exit = button(lower_frame, text="Exit", bg ="white", fg="black", command= ex)
button_exit.pack(side = 'bottom')



lower_frame.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)


#TITLE


label = tk.Label(frame, text="S O C I A L    B O T", font=("Montserrat", 25), bg="white", fg="#222f3e")
label.pack(side="top", fill ="both")




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

v1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("").text
try put `.text` at last of your code

then you can print or use v1 as a value